# How to use IF loop in unix for multiple conditions

Tags: shell, unix, if-statement

I need a logic to implement  the following logic in unix

```
if ( $a !="xyz" || $d !="abc" ) && ( $b= $c))
then
echo "YES WORKING"
fi
```

I tried below code not working

```
if [ [ [ $a != "xyz" ] -o [ $d != "abc" ] ] -a [ "$b" = "$c" ] ]
then
echo "YES WORKING"
fi
```

getting error as

> :[ :] unexpected operator/operand

Comment: `$a !="xyz" || $a !="abc"` is always true

Comment: @fedorqui just now changed the logic Thanks for pointing that

Comment: @TimCastelijns getting error as `:[ :] unexpected operator/operand`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your logic should work easy in shells supporting `[[ ]]`:

```
if [[ ($a != "xyz" || $d != "abc") && $b = "$c" ]]; then
    echo "YES WORKING"
fi
```

Although there's a way for those that doesn't:

```
if ([ ! "$a" = "xyz" ] || [ ! "$d" = "abc" ]) && [ "$b" = "$c" ]; then
    echo "YES WORKING"
fi
```

But that's still inefficient since you'd be summoning subshells, so use `{ }` but the syntax is a little ugly:

```
if { [ ! "$a" = "xyz" ] || [ ! "$d" = "abc" ]; } && [ "$b" = "$c" ]; then
    echo "YES WORKING"
fi
```

Comment: @Pranee What shell are you using? System? Perhaps you should consider the other methods as `[[ ]]` is only supported in modern shells like Zsh and Bash.

Comment: Also, are you running the lines alone, i.e. it's not included with other lines? If they work alone then perhaps it's a problem with other parts of the script.

Comment: your code worked but `"$b" = "$c"` not working may be because `$b= "05/31/2014 "` and `$c="05/31/2014 "`

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like this:

```
[ $a != "xyz" -o $d != "abc" ] && [ "$b" = "$c" ] && echo "YES WORKING"
```

Comment: I forgot about `-o`. Your answer's better than mine with simpler shells. +1